# Python difflib produces weird result on certain inputs

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I was testing how [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) works for per-character diffing of some random inputs, and was surprised to find out the following:

Consider a snippet:

```
import difflib

a = """kydropqfp
tpssubdbw tzibqyqvp llmpwtekn xmubmrjch vcojgxxil
vdrsqhzag xlcldqabb ujccweoha dsooqyyve khilgzjue
jignrbela glvvueqqb qlfehmlkm brkleswiq vvsplffjf
yjuoivyjr wtfueypmo pkvlmbcnh tesuistya zbf"""

blist = list(a)
blist[23] = 'a'
b = ''.join(blist)

print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(a, b)))
```

It provides the expected result:

```
--- 

+++ 

@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@

 t
 z
 i
-b
+a
 q
 y
 q
```

However, if we add only a single `n` character at the end of the input:

```
a = """kydropqfp
tpssubdbw tzibqyqvp llmpwtekn xmubmrjch vcojgxxil
vdrsqhzag xlcldqabb ujccweoha dsooqyyve khilgzjue
jignrbela glvvueqqb qlfehmlkm brkleswiq vvsplffjf
yjuoivyjr wtfueypmo pkvlmbcnh tesuistya zbfn"""
```

Then, for some reason, the context after the found diff is not limited to 3 chars:

```
--- 

+++ 

@@ -21,184 +21,184 @@

 t
 z
 i
-b
-q
-y
-q
-v
-p
- 
-l
-l
-m
-p
-w
-t
-e
-k
-n
- 
-x
-m
-u
-b
-m
-r
-j
-c
-h
- 
-v
-c
-o
-j
-g
-x
-x
-i
-l
-

-v
-d
-r
-s
-q
-h
-z
-a
-g
- 
-x
-l
-c
-l
-d
-q
-a
-b
-b
- 
-u
-j
-c
-c
-w
-e
-o
-h
-a
- 
-d
-s
-o
-o
-q
-y
-y
-v
-e
- 
-k
-h
-i
-l
-g
-z
-j
-u
-e
-

-j
-i
-g
-n
-r
-b
-e
-l
-a
- 
-g
-l
-v
-v
-u
-e
-q
-q
-b
- 
-q
-l
-f
-e
-h
-m
-l
-k
-m
- 
-b
-r
-k
-l
-e
-s
-w
-i
-q
- 
-v
-v
-s
-p
-l
-f
-f
-j
-f
-

-y
-j
-u
-o
-i
-v
-y
-j
-r
- 
-w
-t
-f
-u
-e
-y
-p
-m
-o
- 
-p
-k
-v
-l
-m
-b
-c
-n
-h
- 
-t
-e
-s
-u
-i
-s
-t
-y
-a
- 
-z
-b
-f
-n
+a
+q
+y
+q
+v
+p
+ 
+l
+l
+m
+p
+w
+t
+e
+k
+n
+ 
+x
+m
+u
+b
+m
+r
+j
+c
+h
+ 
+v
+c
+o
+j
+g
+x
+x
+i
+l
+

+v
+d
+r
+s
+q
+h
+z
+a
+g
+ 
+x
+l
+c
+l
+d
+q
+a
+b
+b
+ 
+u
+j
+c
+c
+w
+e
+o
+h
+a
+ 
+d
+s
+o
+o
+q
+y
+y
+v
+e
+ 
+k
+h
+i
+l
+g
+z
+j
+u
+e
+

+j
+i
+g
+n
+r
+b
+e
+l
+a
+ 
+g
+l
+v
+v
+u
+e
+q
+q
+b
+ 
+q
+l
+f
+e
+h
+m
+l
+k
+m
+ 
+b
+r
+k
+l
+e
+s
+w
+i
+q
+ 
+v
+v
+s
+p
+l
+f
+f
+j
+f
+

+y
+j
+u
+o
+i
+v
+y
+j
+r
+ 
+w
+t
+f
+u
+e
+y
+p
+m
+o
+ 
+p
+k
+v
+l
+m
+b
+c
+n
+h
+ 
+t
+e
+s
+u
+i
+s
+t
+y
+a
+ 
+z
+b
+f
+n
```

Does anyone have an explanation of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Under Python 2.7.10, I get very different results between `print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(a, b)))` and `print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(b, a)))` (`a` and `b` swapped around):

```
>>> a = """kydropqfp
... tpssubdbw tzibqyqvp llmpwtekn xmubmrjch vcojgxxil
... vdrsqhzag xlcldqabb ujccweoha dsooqyyve khilgzjue
... jignrbela glvvueqqb qlfehmlkm brkleswiq vvsplffjf
... yjuoivyjr wtfueypmo pkvlmbcnh tesuistya zbfn"""
>>> print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(a, b)))
--- 

+++ 

@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@

t
z
i
-b
+a
q
y
q
@@ -201,4 +201,3 @@

z
b
f
-n
>>> print('\n'.join(difflib.unified_diff(b, a)))
--- 

+++ 

@@ -21,183 +21,184 @@

t
z
i
-a
-q
-y
-q
-v
-p
- 
-l
-l
-m
-p
-w
-t
-e
-k
-n
- 
-x
-m
-u
-b
-m
-r
-j
-c
-h
- 
-v
-c
-o
-j
-g
-x
-x
-i
-l
-

-v
-d
-r
-s
-q
-h
-z
-a
-g
- 
-x
-l
-c
-l
-d
-q
-a
-b
-b
- 
-u
-j
-c
-c
-w
-e
-o
-h
-a
- 
-d
-s
-o
-o
-q
-y
-y
-v
-e
- 
-k
-h
-i
-l
-g
-z
-j
-u
-e
-

-j
-i
-g
-n
-r
-b
-e
-l
-a
- 
-g
-l
-v
-v
-u
-e
-q
-q
-b
- 
-q
-l
-f
-e
-h
-m
-l
-k
-m
- 
-b
-r
-k
-l
-e
-s
-w
-i
-q
- 
-v
-v
-s
-p
-l
-f
-f
-j
-f
-

-y
-j
-u
-o
-i
-v
-y
-j
-r
- 
-w
-t
-f
-u
-e
-y
-p
-m
-o
- 
-p
-k
-v
-l
-m
-b
-c
-n
-h
- 
-t
-e
-s
-u
-i
-s
-t
-y
-a
- 
-z
-b
-f
+b
+q
+y
+q
+v
+p
+ 
+l
+l
+m
+p
+w
+t
+e
+k
+n
+ 
+x
+m
+u
+b
+m
+r
+j
+c
+h
+ 
+v
+c
+o
+j
+g
+x
+x
+i
+l
+

+v
+d
+r
+s
+q
+h
+z
+a
+g
+ 
+x
+l
+c
+l
+d
+q
+a
+b
+b
+ 
+u
+j
+c
+c
+w
+e
+o
+h
+a
+ 
+d
+s
+o
+o
+q
+y
+y
+v
+e
+ 
+k
+h
+i
+l
+g
+z
+j
+u
+e
+

+j
+i
+g
+n
+r
+b
+e
+l
+a
+ 
+g
+l
+v
+v
+u
+e
+q
+q
+b
+ 
+q
+l
+f
+e
+h
+m
+l
+k
+m
+ 
+b
+r
+k
+l
+e
+s
+w
+i
+q
+ 
+v
+v
+s
+p
+l
+f
+f
+j
+f
+

+y
+j
+u
+o
+i
+v
+y
+j
+r
+ 
+w
+t
+f
+u
+e
+y
+p
+m
+o
+ 
+p
+k
+v
+l
+m
+b
+c
+n
+h
+ 
+t
+e
+s
+u
+i
+s
+t
+y
+a
+ 
+z
+b
+f
+n
>>>
```

`difflib` has [strange parts](https://carreau.github.io/posts/08-Dear-DiffLib.html). The algorithm used is an old one that attempts to 'look good', but obviously there are some cases where it doesn't work. I haven't looked into the code to tell you *why* it behaves like this, but I hope this shows you that the built-in `difflib` is good, but not the best. Unfortunately, there do not seem to be an supported [alternatives](https://github.com/Carreau/difflib2.py).